# Is personal loan interest deductable from other income / income for capital gains

Tags: income-tax, india, deposits, personal-loan

Say I take a personal loan and invest that amount on P2P lending platform, or in a high yeild FD, or in the stock market. Is the loan interest that I pay for this loan eligible to be deducted from the FD interest and the capital gains in India?